# Publish two folders using TeamCity build artifacts

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I want to publish two folders using TeamCity build artifacts. I edited the artifacts path in general settings of the project as

```
%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/module1/build/output
%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/module2/build/output
```

But I am getting only one folder as build artifacts. How can I solve this.

Comment: is one of the folders empty? Teamcity does not output empty folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your artifacts path to move the artifacts to explicit paths within the artifacts directory.
For example:

```
%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/module1/build/output => Module1Output
%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/module2/build/output => Module2Output
```

Make sure they're separated by a new line.

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the build log in the Publishing Artifacts section, can you see any mention of module1, hopefully an error? What does your Artifact paths configuration look like now?

Comment: Yes the error was like `module1/build/output` not found. The path was `outputs` and not `output`. Now I corrected it and got it right.